# Retrieving rows from a table using pairs of IDs from a separate table

Tags: python, pandas, csv, linked-tables

Given two files,

- `sentences_detailed.csv` contains 3 columns (`ID`, `LANG` and `TEXT`)
- `links.csv` contains 2 columns (`ID1` and `ID2`), the `ID*` is linked to the `ID` column in `sentences_detailed.csv`

Sample of `sentences_detailed.csv`:

```
ID LANG TEXT
123 eng I want you to meet my parents.
456 eng I'm on your side.
789 eng I did not want to alarm you. 
567 kor 부모님을 만나길 원해.
2352 jpn 私はあなたの側にいます。
```

And sample of `links.csv`:

```
ID1 ID2
123 567
2352 456
```

**How do I create a new DataFrame such that I get the respective `LANG` and `TEXT` column from `sentences_detailed.csv` using the pairs of IDs in `links.csv`?**

The desired output DataFrame should look something like:

```
ID1 ID2 LANG1 LANG2 TEXT1 TEXT2
123 567 eng kor I want you to meet my parents. 부모님을 만나길 원해.
2352 456 jpn eng 私はあなたの側にいます。I'm on your side.
```

I've tried this:

```
sent_details_csv = """ID    LANG    TEXT
123 eng I want you to meet my parents.
456 eng I'm on your side.
789 eng I did not want to alarm you. 
567 kor 부모님을 만나길 원해.
2352    jpn 私はあなたの側にいます。"""

links_csv = """ID1  ID2
123 567
2352    456
"""

from io import StringIO

sent_details = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sent_details_csv), sep='\t')
links = pd.read_csv(StringIO(links_csv), sep='\t')

for idx, row in links.iterrows():
    src_idx, trg_idx = row['ID1'], row['ID2']

    try:
        src = sent_details[sent_details['ID'] == src_idx][['TEXT', 'LANG']].iloc[0]
        trg = sent_details[sent_details['ID'] == trg_idx][['TEXT', 'LANG']].iloc[0]
    except: 
        continue

    print('\t'.join(map(str, [src_idx, trg_idx, src['LANG'], trg['LANG'], src['TEXT'], trg['TEXT']])))
```

The code above works for a small dataset but the actual `sentences_detailed.csv` is 6,000,000+ rows and `links.csv` is ~13,000,000 rows.

Trying to filter out `sent_details` given a source and target idx for each `links` row gets becomes costly.

There must be a better more "pandas-ic" way to do this.

---

The full dataset is on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/how-to-get-parallel-sentences-from-tatoeba

The answers from Dark, Zero and COLDSPEED are good but when there're duplicates in the sentences_detailed.csv and links.csv , they throw some errors.

Comment: Are there duplicated IDs? Like `123,567`  and `123,456`

Comment: Yes there are duplicate IDs. Assuming that there are no duplicate IDs, will it be simpler?

Comment: @alvas I've added a method that should work regardless of whether or not there are dupes in your links df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fast way of doing to is by divide and merge i.e

```
one = df[df['ID'].isin(links['ID1'])].copy()
two = df[df['ID'].isin(links['ID2'])].copy()

two['NEW_ID'] = two['ID'].map(links.set_index('ID2')['ID1'])

one.merge(two,left_on='ID',right_on='NEW_ID',suffixes=('1', '2'))

     ID1 LANG1                         TEXT1       ID2  LANG2       TEXT2      NEW_ID  
0   123    eng     I want you to meet my parents.  567    kor  부모님을 만나길 원해.     123  
1  2352    jpn             私はあなたの側にいます。    456    eng  I'm on your side.    2352
```

Mapping didn't work due to the presence of duplicate IDs, So you can use dual merge i.e

```
one.merge(two.merge(links,left_on='ID',right_on='ID2'),left_on='ID',right_on='ID1',suffixes=('1', '2')))

 ID1 LANG1                           TEXT1  ID2 LANG2              TEXT2  \
0   123   eng  I want you to meet my parents.  567   kor       부모님을 만나길 원해.   
1  2352   jpn                    私はあなたの側にいます。  456   eng  I'm on your side.   

    ID1  ID2  
0   123  567  
1  2352  456
```

Based on the actual data you can simply cross merge same dataframe since you have the same column names i.e

```
sec = sent_details.merge(links)

sec.merge(sec, left_on=['Sentence id','Translation id'],right_on=['Translation id','Sentence id'], suffixes=(1,2))
```

Comment: Ah, yes `'Reindexing only valid with uniquely'`. Only works for unique indices.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know it's possible to do both `left_on` and `right_on`. Let me try.

Comment: I think it's not merging the right thing. The edited answer will repeat the `Text1` and `Text2`.  The output of the edited answer is on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/how-to-get-parallel-sentences-from-tatoeba/ .

Comment: The dual merge is missing from the `one.merge(two.merge(links),on='Sentence id',suffixes=('1', '2'))`

Comment: @alvas it was a misconception, you can cross merge. Check out the last edit. It worked in kaggle kernel for me.

Comment: You can check here https://www.kaggle.com/bharathsh/how-to-get-parallel-sentences-from-tatoeba

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1]** Using `merge` and `concat`

```
In [328]: pd.concat([df2[['ID'+x]].merge(df1.add_suffix(x)) for x in ['1', '2']], axis=1)
Out[328]:
    ID1 LANG1                           TEXT1  ID2 LANG2              TEXT2
0   123   eng  I want you to meet my parents.  567   kor       부모님을 만나길 원해.
1  2352   jpn                    私はあなたの側にいます。  456   eng  I'm on your side.
```

**Option 2]**

One way would be to use `map` with `set_index`

```
In [307]: df11 = df1.set_index('ID')

In [308]: for c in ['LANG', 'TEXT']:
     ...:     for x in ['1', '2']:
     ...:         df2[c + x] = df2['ID' + x].map(df11[c])
     ...:

In [309]: df2
Out[309]:
    ID1  ID2 LANG1 LANG2                           TEXT1              TEXT2
0   123  567   eng   kor  I want you to meet my parents.       부모님을 만나길 원해.
1  2352  456   jpn   eng                    私はあなたの側にいます。  I'm on your side.
```

---

Details

```
In [303]: df1
Out[303]:
     ID LANG                            TEXT
0   123  eng  I want you to meet my parents.
1   456  eng               I'm on your side.
2   789  eng   I did not want to alarm you.
3   567  kor                    부모님을 만나길 원해.
4  2352  jpn                    私はあなたの側にいます。

In [304]: df2
Out[304]:
    ID1  ID2
0   123  567
1  2352  456
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ID*` columns in `links` as indexers to the `sent_details` columns, using `loc` -

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
```

```
i = df1.loc[df2.ID1].reset_index().add_suffix('_1')
j = df1.loc[df2.ID2].reset_index().add_suffix('_2')

pd.concat([i, j], 1)

   ID_1 LANG_1                          TEXT_1  ID_2 LANG_2                 TEXT_2
0   123    eng  I want you to meet my parents.   567    kor       부모님을 만나길 원해.
1  2352    jpn          私はあなたの側にいます。   456    eng       I'm on your side.
```

Where -

```
df1 = sent_details
```

And,

```
df2 = links
```

---

If you want the result sorted as per your requirements, use `sort_index` -

```
v = pd.concat([i, j], 1)
v.reindex(columns=sorted(v.columns, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]))

   ID_1  ID_2 LANG_1 LANG_2                          TEXT_1                 TEXT_2
0   123   567    eng    kor  I want you to meet my parents.       부모님을 만나길 원해.
1  2352   456    jpn    eng           私はあなたの側にいます。      I'm on your side.
```

Comment: The answer works for the example in the OP but it's looks like it's a lot more complicated in the real data and the answer is not getting the right mappings to the `ID_1` and `ID_2` =(

Comment: The actual data is on https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/how-to-get-parallel-sentences-from-tatoeba